# Best way to compile a C library as part of a Cocoa project

Tags: macos, cocoa, compilation, installation, rabbitmq

I'm unfortunately a little uneducated in these waters so apologies if my terminology is off.

I am writing an application for Mac OS X that uses the rabbitmq-c library (https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c). Just running on my computer I can make and install the library to the /usr/local/include and link against that in my project, and everything works well. When I roll out this code I want to be able to include this with the application installer somehow, any suggestions on how to best include a compiled c library like this in the project? Is it possible to include it in the actual application bundle? Should I write an installer (preferrably with a GUI) that compiles it and links it when downloaded?

Comment: Does it need to be installed? Most app these days are self-contained and have everything in their app's bundle. Even 3rd party frameworks work just fine. I've found it easiest to just build a wrapper framework for 3rd party stuff and include that framework wherever I need it.

Comment: The important point is: is the library dynamic or static?  The former would need including in the app bundle (`Frameworks` directory) and the latter would be linked into the main executable.

Comment: The library is dynamic.